# How can I control the ui material table height automatically?

Tags: material-ui

I am using the Table component available in material-ui in my React JS code with a single row. I have an "Add" icon button for adding desired  number of rows. How can I expand and shrink the table height, depending on the number of rows.  If the number of rows (excluding header and footer) exceed 20, then I want to put a scroll on the right. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at this solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/basictable-material-demo-with-scroll-jsxwk?file=/demo.js.

It has a default row size of 4 that can be changed by a text field and will automatically resize the table accordingly, the scroller appears depending on the content, you don't have to worry about it.

The trick is customizing the TableContainer and Table's CSS:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tableContainer: {
    overflowY: "auto"
  },
  table: { //...
    height: "100%",
    overflowY: "scroll"
  }, //...
});
```

And control the table container's height here:

```js
const classes = useStyles();
const [maxRows, setMaxRows] = useState(4);
//...
return <TableContainer
        component={Paper}
        className={classes.tableContainer}
        style={{
          maxHeight: maxRows * ROW_HEIGHT + HEAD_ROW_HEIGHT
        }}
      >
  <Table stickyHeader className={classes.table}> 
    {/*...*/}
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work anymore: the new releases broke it as you didn't specify a proper release version of te packages.

Comment: Thanks! updated.